# How do I hide an HTML element before the page loads using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have some JQuery code that shows or hides a div.

```
$("div#extraControls").show();   // OR .hide()
```

I initially want the div to be not visible so I used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div#extraControls").hide();
});
```

However, on the browser, the content loads visible for a second before disappearing, which is not what I want.

How do I set the hide the element before the page loads whilst keeping the ability to show hide it dynamically with a script?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
div.hidden
{
   display: none
}

<div id="extraControls" class="hidden">
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div#extraControls").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: +1 One thing to note is that if the user has disabled JavaScript in the browser, the whole page stays hidden.

Comment: From my experience some browsers will not load media (eg. images) in elements which are hidden using `display:none` or `opacity:0`. I'd recommend using `visibility:hidden` instead.

Comment: @mq.chen Thanks for the warning, however the visibility tag does not allow the content to be toggled with the .hide() command.

Comment: @mq.chen Thank you for your suggestion, I think this is better as it's just a hidden tag on each element instead of having to use css to hide it and remove the class, genius!

Comment: I'm pretty sure $("#your-class-id").show(); would still work even hiding it that way as well.

Answer (score 4):

Make a css class

```
.hidden {
display: none;
}
```

Add this to any element you don't want to be visible when loading the page. Then use `$("div#extraControls").show();` to display it again.

Answer (score 3):

With CSS3 you can actually hide content until a page loads by taking advantage of the `:only-child` selector.

[Here is a demonstration of how to do this](https://rawgithub.com/brettryan/9000148/raw/1c72d79085a3f129522a1a6d40a353223cf83863/hide-until-load-css.html). The basic idea is that CSS while loading will add a single node to the DOM while loading that node and its child nodes. Further, once a second child is added to the given parent node the `:only-child` selector rule is broken. We match against this selector and set `display: none` to hide the given node.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

  <head>
    <title>Hide content until loaded with CSS</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      .hide-single-child > :only-child {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class='hide-single-child'>
      <div>
        <h1>Content Hidden</h1>
        <script>
          alert('Note that content is hidden until you click "Ok".');
        </script>
      </div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

In CSS:

```
#extraControls { display: none; }
```

Or in HTML:

```
<div id="extraControls" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#toggleMe //Keep this in your .css file
{
display:none;
visibility:inherit;
background-color:#d2d8c9;    
}


 <a href="#" onclick="return false;">Expand Me</a>
 ///this way u can make a link to act like a button too

 <div id="toggleMe">  //this will be hidden during the page load
  //your elements
 </div>

///if you decide to make it display on a click, follow below:
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script> //make sure u include jquery.js file in ur project
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a").click(function () {
            $('#toggleMe').toggle("slow"); //Animation effect
        });
    });
</script>

///Now for every alternate click, it shows and hides, but during page load; its hidden.
//Hope this helps you guys ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to load javascript function over page is loaded, is

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   // code here
});
```

In your case

```
div.hidden
{
   display: none
}

<div id="extraControls" class="hidden">
</div>

$(window).bind("load", function() {
   $("div#extraControls").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style at the top most of the html code.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    div.extraControls{display: none !important;}
</style>
```

and add the following script at the end most of the html code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('div.extraControls').show();
    });
</script>
```

Don't forget to add `class="extraControls"` in div element.

You may also use `id` instead of class.

For id replace `div.extraControls` with `div#extraControls` and `$('div.extraControls')` with `$('div#extraControls')`

**Use following script to enable Javascript forcefully if it's disabled on browser.**

Tested on GC

```
<noscript>
<style>
body, html{overflow:hidden}
     #JsEnable {display:none}
/* Enable Javascript Popup by key2blogging */
         #Key2bloggingNoscript {background:rgba(0,0,0,0.85);padding:0;position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;top:-100px;right:0;z-index:1000;opacity:1;visibility:visible;height:auto;}
         #Key2bloggingNoscript svg {width:100px; height:100px}
         #Key2bloggingNoscript svg path {fill:#fff}
         #Key2bloggingNoscript .isiNoscript{background-color:#34495E;color:#fff;position:absolute;text-align:center;padding:0 30px 30px 30px;margin:auto;top:30%;left:0;right:0;font-size:1.5rem;font-weight:400;line-height:1.5em;max-width:670px;box-shadow:0 20px 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);border:15px solid rgba(0,0,0,.07); overflow:hidden; transition:all .6s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1); -webkit-transform:translateZ(0); transform:translateZ(0); backface-visibility:visible; transition:all .2s ease-in-out,visibility 0s; transform-origin:bottom center; pointer-events:auto; transform:rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) scale(1); opacity:1; animation:key2BloggingWobble .5s; -moz-animation: key2BloggingWobble .5s; -webkit-animation:key2BloggingWobble .5s; -o-animation:key2BloggingWobble .5s}
         #Key2bloggingNoscript .isiNoscript:hover{box-shadow:0 20px 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}
         #Key2bloggingNoscript .isiNoscript h4, #Key2bloggingNoscript .isiNoscript .JSEnable{display:inline-block;background:rgba(0,0,0,.07);padding:5px 25px 15px 25px;font-size:2.2rem;font-weight:500;margin-bottom:20px}
    </style>
</noscript>

<noscript>
<div id='Key2bloggingNoscript'>
<div class='isiNoscript'><span class='JSEnable'>Enable Javascript</span>
<br/>
<svg viewBox='0 0 24 24'>
<path d='M3,3H21V21H3V3M7.73,18.04C8.13,18.89 8.92,19.59 10.27,19.59C11.77,19.59 12.8,18.79 12.8,17.04V11.26H11.1V17C11.1,17.86 10.75,18.08 10.2,18.08C9.62,18.08 9.38,17.68 9.11,17.21L7.73,18.04M13.71,17.86C14.21,18.84 15.22,19.59 16.8,19.59C18.4,19.59 19.6,18.76 19.6,17.23C19.6,15.82 18.79,15.19 17.35,14.57L16.93,14.39C16.2,14.08 15.89,13.87 15.89,13.37C15.89,12.96 16.2,12.64 16.7,12.64C17.18,12.64 17.5,12.85 17.79,13.37L19.1,12.5C18.55,11.54 17.77,11.17 16.7,11.17C15.19,11.17 14.22,12.13 14.22,13.4C14.22,14.78 15.03,15.43 16.25,15.95L16.67,16.13C17.45,16.47 17.91,16.68 17.91,17.26C17.91,17.74 17.46,18.09 16.76,18.09C15.93,18.09 15.45,17.66 15.09,17.06L13.71,17.86Z'/>
</svg>
<br/>Javascript is disabled on your Browser. To use <data:blog.title.escaped/> turn on Javascript in the browser settings.</div>
</div>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is insert a inline `script` tag at the end of the document, or immediately after the div with id "extraControls". Should be fire a little sooner than.

```
<div id="extraControls">i want to be invisible!</div>
<script type="text/javascript">$("div#extraControls").hide()</script>
```

Of course you could do this server-side as well, but maybe there's a good reason you don't want to do that (like, have the controls visible if the browser does NOT support javascript).