# Close div on click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use this code to close a div onclick:

```
;(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        $('.m-help .m-text').hide();
        $('.m-help')
            .on('click', function (event) {
             var close = $(event.target).closest('.m-link-close-button').length;
            $(this).find('.m-text')[close ? 'hide' : 'show']();

        });

    });
    $(document).bind('m-ajax-after', function (e, selectors) {
        $('.m-help .m-text').hide();
        $('.m-help')
            .on('click', function (event) {
             var close = $(event.target).closest('.m-link-close-button').length;
            $(this).find('.m-text')[close ? 'hide' : 'show']();

        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

And with this HTML:

```
<div class="m-help">
    <div class="m-text" style="width: 40px;">
        <?php echo $_helpHtml ?>
        <a href="#" class="m-link-close-button"><span>x</span></a>
    </div>
    <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="details m-link"></a>
</div>
```

This works fine, but when the page loads, the div is first displayed and after loading the entire page the div is closed.
Why does this load first open and after the entire page is loaded closed?

How do I need to edit this code, that the div is closed directly on loading the page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I hide an HTML element before the page loads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951053/how-do-i-hide-an-html-element-before-the-page-loads)

Comment: @Jelle This is a weird question, because your code is really clean, rather high-level, with a closure, an event delegation, super compact syntax (`$(this).find('.m-text')[close ? 'hide' : 'show']()`) and all... So you definitely don't look like a newbie, yet the solution to your problem is really for beginners (a simple `document.ready` matter). Funny paradox :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use css display on div directly. 
Your code should be like this

```
<div class="m-text" style="width: 40px; display:none">
    <?php echo $_helpHtml ?>
    <a href="#" class="m-link-close-button"><span>x</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript is executing on page load once the document is ready, so if you're relying on JS to hide it this won't happen until then.

If this is a problem, use CSS to hide your div element and then show it when required with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I need to edit this code to flip it?

Comment: Don't be lazy. There are plenty of examples of this on Stack Overflow and other sites. Do a little digging.

One example I quickly found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951053/how-do-i-hide-an-html-element-before-the-page-loads

Answer (score 0):

By Default use css to hide the div.

```
.m-help .m-text{
display:none;
}.
```

when ever you need to show the div,add another class using `.addClass` name it as some divShow.

```
.divShow{
display:block !important;
}
```

and remove the class when div needs to be closed

Answer (score 0):

Hiding components using jquery onLoad or onReady events, makes component wait for entire documents to load.

So instead of using `$('.m-help .m-text').hide();` in JS file,

Use `.m-help .m-text'{display:none}` in your css file. This will hide those components by default. And whenever necessary show them using JS

**NOTE**: Don't use `display:none !important` property, it will create unnecessary complications.