# Hide a table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to keep a table hidden at the time of loading. Later I would like to slideDown that table to show when a link is clicked.I write this code to hide that table.

$('.table_div').hide();

I placed that table in a div. Then I hide that div.

My problem is at time of loading first the table display for a moment then the table hide. I would like to prevent this display. Thanks

Comment: Search at SO, before! 

[How do I hide an HTML element before the page loads][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2951074/2990234

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I hide an HTML element before the page loads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951053/how-do-i-hide-an-html-element-before-the-page-loads)

Answer (score 5):

To prevent that Add Css Property to `.table_div`

```
.table_div {
     display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add css to hide it

```
.table_div {
     display: none;
}
```

---

after load page just show it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".table_div").slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all jquery statements in between these curly braces:

```
$(document).ready(function(){}
```

So that all scripts execute only after document is loaded.
For the starting display, use

```
.table_div{display:none;}
```

in the css page. Does it work now?